# Regex - match table tag by its ID fragment

Tags: html, xml, regex, parsing, dom

I didn't got it wrong. The aplication's running .net 3.5.
There are no parsers working for 3.5, I swear.

I'm trying fetch a table tag, which has a keyword fragment within its ID.

I tried using this regex

```
"<table.*ctl01.*>.*</table>"
```

some listing:

```
 <table class="Default_GridClass" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CustomerByLocation_ViewPanelStandAlone_ViewPanel_Grid_ctl01">
```

this table tag is located inside its two parent's table tags.

actually, the parent tables contain no "ctl01" fragment in their ID. but, using my regex i get all 3 tables instead of that one

Comment: One of the most famous questions on StackOverflow and relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: definitely an up-vote for above comment.  Look into something like Html Agility Pack to convert the html into a tree representation.  http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: @JosephHopkins , I have already tried agility pack. It's not working for 3.5 as I stated above

Comment: ok - try being non-greedy on selectors.  <table(.*?)ctl01(.*?)>([^<]*?)</table>

Comment: @JosephHopkins , nope. Doesn't work. Still getting all tables within the document.

Comment: Try `<table[^>]*ctl01[^>]*>[^>]*</table>`

Comment: In your example source, where is the end tag? Is it on the next line? But the regex assumes everything on the same line.